# react and bootstrap v4 delay collapse to render component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I am using React and bootstrap 4 to generate a collapsible div. Inside this div I have another React component, like this:

**ComponentA**

```
<a name={name}
    className={'btn btn-primary'}
    data-toggle={'collapse'}
    href={'#collapseId'}
    role={'button'} aria-expanded={'false'}
    aria-controls={'collapseId'}>
    collapse
</a>
<div id='collapseId'>
    <ComponentB/>
</div>
```

This works correctly, but when I render ComponentA multiple times (I need to render it more than 20 times) I get performance issues, because ComponentB includes many divs and buttons.

So what I want to do is to render conditionally ComponentB but keep bootstrap's collapse transitions.

Now, if I want to conditionally render, I do this:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state={collapsed=true}
}

conditionalRender(e){
    this.setState(prevState => this.state.collapsed = !prevState.collapsed)
}
```

And then in the render function:

```
<a name={name}
    className={'btn btn-primary'}
    data-toggle={'collapse'}
    href={'#collapseId'}
    role={'button'} aria-expanded={'false'}
    aria-controls={'collapseId'}
    onClick={(e)=>this.conditionalRender(e)}>
    collapse
</a>
<div id='collapseId'>
    {!this.state.collapsed &&
    <ComponentB/>
    }
</div>
```

And it works, BUT the transition is laggy, not fluid and doesn't look good.

Is there a way to delay the transition of the collapsed transition for this to work and be fluid? I've seen some overrides to css transition, but again, not fluid.
Another valid option would be to use the callback function of setState to execute the default anchor's functionality but I don't know how to.

```
bootstrap 4.1
react 16.4.2
```

Comment: I don't know if it can affect performance(I guess not), but curly braces in react always means some variables, you don't need them where you have only strings like in className or data-toggle={'collapse'}

Comment: Also I would add e.preventDefault() in conditionalRender(e)

Comment: @VladislavSorokin yes I would do the preventDefault if I could trigger the normal anchor's behaviour after the setState, but if I do it like it is it will never show the collapsed div.